# Trying to create a return to home screen button using Tkinter, getting not defined traceback

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am trying to code a return to home screen button while closing the current window but I am getting "newWindow is not defined". I am able to navigate to new menus while closing the home screen but not the other way around.

def cardinfobutt() works but def home() doesnt

Heres my code:

```
root = Tk()

def home():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("600x300")
    root.maxsize(600, 300)
    root.minsize(600, 300)
    root.title("eBot")
    newWindow.destroy()

def cardinfobutt():
    newWindow = Tk()
    newWindow.title("Card Information")
    newWindow.geometry("600x300")
    Label(newWindow, text="Card Information").pack()
    homebutton = Button(newWindow, text="Back to Home Screen", padx=50, pady=50, command=home, fg="black", bg="white")
    homebutton.pack()
    root.destroy()
```

tried to use the same process home screen -> other menus, get newWindow is not defined.

def cardinfobutt() works but def home() doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `newWindow.destroy()` and `root.destroy()` will destroy both windows simultaneously.

What you are looking for :

- `root.update()`
- `root.deiconify()`
- `newWindow.destroy()`

Edit: I added `global` and `root.withdraw()` in `home()` function.
I modified your code and added widgets.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

  
def home():
    global newWindow
    root.withdraw()
    newWindow = tk.Toplevel()
    newWindow.geometry("600x300")
    tk.Label(newWindow, text="Card Information").pack()
    homebutton = tk.Button(newWindow, text="Back to Home Screen", padx=50, pady=50, command=show, fg="black", bg="white")
    homebutton.pack()
      

def show():
    root.update()
    root.deiconify()
    newWindow.destroy()
 
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x300")
root.maxsize(600, 300)
root.minsize(600, 300)
root.title("eBot")
 
     
mybutton = tk.Button(root, text = "New Window", command = home)
mybutton.pack(pady = 10)
 
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: that fixed my issue and learned some new things. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using multiple instances of Tk() which is generally discouraged, as each instance runs it's own Tcl interpreter. Have a look at [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged/48045508#48045508)

The easy way to have multiple windows is to create child windows with `Toplevel()`.